# Analysis Unboundness Theorem

Tags: analysis

(1) Consider the interval I = [a, b] and assume that f is a function that is continuous
on I and unbounded on I.
Let d denote the midpoint of the interval I. Let I1 = [a1, b1] denote that half of I
on which f is unbounded. If f is unbounded on both halves, let I1 denote the left
half. Repeat this process so that for each n 2 N the interval In+1 = [an+1, bn+1] be
that half of the interval In on which f is unbounded. If f is unbounded on both
halves, let In+1 denote the left half.
(a) Explain why, under the assumptions stated above, f is unbounded on at least
one of the intervals [a, d] or [d, b].

Comment: $f$ is not unbounded. Continuous functions map compact sets to compact sets.

Comment: @kahen this may very well be a part of a proof of (a particular case) of that statement

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE. For some basic information about writing maths at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latexhelp/notation).

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is bounded on $[a,d]$ and $[d,b]$, say $|f| \le A$ on $[a,d]$ and $|f| \le B$ on $[d,b]$, then $f$ must be bounded on $[a,b]$, since $|f| \le \max\{A,B\}$ on $[a,b]$.

(As pointed out, there are no continuous functions on $[a,b]$ that are unbounded though.)